# Will replacing B23N20 mosfet with B4227 have problems?

Tags: mosfet

I have the microphone amplifier and line Powerpod 410 R that after an analysis I found that one of the output mosfets is in total short.
The short mosfet is this IRFB23N20D, however I don't find it in my country Brazil, but I found this IRFB4227PbF. As I am new to amplifiers using mosfet, I asked for help, I have been reading the datashet of one and the other has some differences as the current supported my question is will I have problems replacing what I found in my country?

DATASHET's:
[IRFB23N20D](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1J_pUKM33x4hG33buZnTg_roV8Vr1lDj0/view?usp=sharing)
[IRFB4227PbF](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irfb4227pbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a401535615eb531e1f)
[IRS2092](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1no6ngva65VHNu7dXHT7Af82eEpOKagDr/view?usp=sharing)

OBSERVATION:
I'm sorry I use google translator, so I may not express myself well.

Comment: The link to the first MOSFET is down. We would need schematics of the Powerpod 410 R to make any decisions, or suggestions.

Comment: _”I don't find it in my country X”_ Digi-Key, Mouser, Farnell ships all over the world except North Korea.

Comment: Okay, I already added the schematic on the post
fixed the first link in the mosfet.
The problem is the delay when any order arrives stays more than 1 month at customs.
I can try to see some others but the closest I found was this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IRFB4427 has lower ON resistance, but very high input/output capacitances.
In a Class D audio amplifier, I would not replace the [IRFB23N20](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irfb23n20d.pdf) with it.
Instead, you can use MOSFETs with similar I/O capacities and currents. (IRFB4020, IRFB5620, FQP19N20, RCX200N20)

Comment: You never really know what you're getting from aliexpress. I would recommend rather looking for devices with similar capacitances, because you definitely have a point that high FET capacitance would be a problem in a class-D amplifier.

Comment: In ali. i do not trust buy semi conductors there

Comment: You can also shop [here](https://uk.farnell.com/infineon/irfb23n20dpbf/mosfet-n-200v-24a-to-220/dp/8648743?scope=partnumberlookahead&ost=IRFB23N20DPBF&searchref=searchlookahead&exaMfpn=true) quickly.

Comment: I'll wait for someone to see if I can use the one I found here, otherwise I care. Added schematic of amplifier in post

Comment: I'm sorry, but the schematic belongs to an older amplifier. Not the "R" version. There are no FETs in it.

Comment: I understood why I thought the scheme was strange, but I convinced myself that this was it, I'll see if I can find the one in the R version

Comment: @csabahu I think it will be easier to photograph joining the two layers of copper and adding transparency, I will do that today and edit the post later.

Comment: @Gabriel L S Saraiva I don't know what FETs you can get, but they would be good: IRFB4020, IRFB5620, FQP19N20, RCX200N20.

Comment: @csabahu P19N20 found it here to sell on several local sites in the country! Only he has a greater resistance that would not be a problem?

Comment: he uses the CI Irs2092 is based on the diagram suggested in the datashet so I could see measuring the resistances and capacitances. I will add the datahset of this CI in the post

Comment: I see the difference in loss is 1.8W due to the higher resistance. So this is not significant. (The switching current is  approx. 6A.)

Comment: Okay so I'm going to use this same "P19N20", Thanks @csabahu  Edit your post and depend on the suggestion there that I mark as solved!